# Pip won't install packages in Venv that are also in system site-packages

Tags: python-3.x, path, pip, site-packages

I realize this topic has so many other SO answers but I haven't been able to find one for my specific problem.

I am using python 3.7 on windows and create my virtual environments using venv. When I activate my virtual environment and call `pip list --local`, I get a list of all my system-site-packages rather than the empty list I would expect for a new environment (venv is supposed to default to no site-packages https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

However, if I look in the virtual environments site-packages folder, it is empty as expected.
This is an issue, because pip won't install some packages into the virtual environment as it thinks they're already there (it sees the system-packages).

I think this has something to do with my **path variable**, possibly that I'm using the system version of pip rather than the one in my virtual environment. But I don't know how to set up the path variable to fix it.

Currently, my path includes both my python directory in `Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32` and also the `\Scripts` folder within that directory.

Here's the result of trying to install numpy in a new virtual environment:

```
(Venv) C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Python_Projects\ML\>pip install numpy
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\Bob\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (1.16.2+mkl)
```

Comment: Use `echo %PATH%`, then `where python` and `where pip` to check that everything points to the right places when the virtual environment is activated.

Comment: @sinoroc  `where python` returned the desired result (a path to the scripts in my virtual environment). `where pip` returned the following: `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).` I just looked in the 'Scripts' folder in my virtual environment and it doesn't contain 'pip.exe'. I'm not sure how this is happening when creating virtual environments using venv?

Comment: The call `python -m pip` is always a valid replacement for the direct call to `pip`. So you could try to use that instead. I would also simply try to delete the virtual environment and create a new one, and see if `pip` is available in this one.

Comment: I removed `Users\Bob\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts` from my path and re-made the virtual environment. It now works perfectly (Except I now have to use `python -m pip` outside the virtual environment). A reasonable compromise. Thanks for your help

Comment: Seems like there is something wrong with your setup. I would consider uninstalling Python entirely and start from scratch. Optionally, and if you're comfortable enough with the idea, I would advise to skip the installation of `pip` entirely and only ever use `pip` when inside a virtual environment.